# Error connecting PACS server Dicom.Network.DicomAssociationRejectedException: "[reason: CallingAENotRecognized]'

Tags: dicom, fo-dicom

I'm very new to deal with DICOM, I was trying to get some patient related dicom file(s) from a public remote server:
*https://www.dicomserver.co.uk*. using **fo-dicom** and it works fine, **but** when I switched to private server it shows me the error below when performing the call:
**Dicom.Network.DicomAssociationRejectedException: 'Association rejected [result: Permanent; source: ServiceUser; reason: CallingAENotRecognized]'**
and here's the cood snippet:

```
private static readonly string QRServerHost = "ServerIP";
private static readonly int QRServerPort = PortNumber;
private static readonly string QRServerAET = "ServerAET"
private static readonly string AET = "Test";

var client = new DicomClient(QRServerHost, QRServerPort, false, AET, QRServerAET);
                client.NegotiateAsyncOps();
```

Comment: Are the parameters (IP, especially AET) "anonymized" in your post or are these the actual values you are using in association establishment?

Comment: Server's related data are actual data (IP, Port, and serverAET) , AET is a random string I came up with ( as it works fine on https://www.dicomserver.co.uk ) I can query it using any random AET

Comment: @kritzel_sw am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Should I ask the PACS server admin offline (over email or something ) to register an Entity for me on the server? if so, what information needed from my side to share with the admin?

Comment: @MoatazAmer the admin likely needs your AET ("Test") and IP

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli so I just need to send him an IP, and an AET (just text) ... (I.e. 10.0.0.10 , and "Test" ), that's it?  ( Although I never needed to do that while contacting a public dicom server "dicomserver.co.uk" )

Comment: @MoatazAmer: See my comment to answer

Comment: @MoatazAmer: AET, IP and Port should be negotiated both ways. You need to know your own and the remote and the remote (PACS) needs to know your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The exception:

> Dicom.Network.DicomAssociationRejectedException: 'Association rejected [result: Permanent; source: ServiceUser; reason: CallingAENotRecognized]'

is standard DICOM Network exception. It indicates that SCP need to know the SCU in advance. This can be done by registering your application (AE Title and IP Address is common) on SCP.

Many SCP implementations do not enforce this registration. I do not know how "https://www.dicomserver.co.uk/" works; most probably, is does not need the registration in advance.

In cases where pre-registration is needed, it might be for security or financial reasons.

Comment: ok then I'll check the AET registration with the PACS server's admin.

Comment: The documentation says that the "public" DICOM server accepts any AET both ways. But since the problem was described to be in conjunction with "switched to private server", it sounded suspicious to me.